# TDNN with multiple hidden layer

Tags: matlab

I found this code for a Time Delay Neural Network (TDNN) in matlab and it contains only one hidden layer. Can i put more than one and if yes how can i do it?

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
net = timedelaynet(1:2,10);
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,T);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Ts,Y);
```

i have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
net = timedelaynet(1:2,{10,10});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in the argument you do not want a cell-style parameter, `{10, 10}` in this case. Try `[10, 10]` as a vector, then the command could be:

```
net = timedelaynet(1:2,[10,10]);
```